# Comparison operations in cron

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I'd like to configure cron to run script on the first day of every month if it is a working day. If the month starts on a weekend, I want the script to be run on the first following week day.
I tried do it this way

```
0 9 1-3 * * dom=$(date +\%d); dow=$(date +\%u); [[ $dow -lt 6 && (( $dom -eq 1 || $dow -eq 1 )) ]] && script.sh
```

This works in bash, but seems like cron can't execute comparisons.

Comment: I've found the way to set up scheduler like
0 9 1W * *
but I really don't want to play with system time to test it and wonder if it is possible to make cron work with comparisons

Comment: Why also not pass the condition to the script within if

Comment: Yes, overall it would be a solution, but I now wonder if this type of cron setup is possible

Comment: place a line SHELL=/bin/bash near the start of your crontab file.

Comment: However, I would put the stuff you are doing now in its own bash script, make it executable, and simply call that script from the crontab file; much cleaner, and also takes the debugging out from the crontab file into a regular script.

Comment: I do advise you to keep the SHELL line in the crontab file though, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: SHELL line made the magic work, thanks! My example was just a simplified task I was going to solve. Of course I have executable scripts with conditions, but I was really curious about possibility to run comparisons in cron.

Comment: `[[ $dom -eq 1 || $dow -eq 1 ]]` is going to run it twice if the first day of the month is on the weekend, and it'll run on every Monday (see [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_1-3_*_1-5)).

Comment: Yes, you are right, to make it run exactly once, those conditions should be changed

Answer (score 0):

By advice of [Roadowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2849202/roadowl), adding

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

at the beginning of cron file made things work.